# SQL Related: Summing the same category and selecting first record only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some assisting with understanding how to tackle this:

I have a group of items with the same style but different suppliers.

There are 2 tables which links together via the priority of the items.

What I am trying to achieve: When a user selects multiple items and if they have the same style it needs to group them together and only display the ONE record of the item that has a order of 1 without using the top 1

This is what i tried:

```
DECLARE @ItemKeys dbo.Ids

INSERT INTO @ItemKeys
Values 
(2428413),
(2428620),
(2658066),
(2658103)

select  ItemKey
from test.ItemLink1 il1  
JOIN test.ItemLinkR  ilr
    ON il1.PriorityId = ilr.PriorityId
JOIN @ItemKeys iks
    ON ilr.ItemKey = iks.Id 
GROUP BY ItemKey 
HAVING MAX(Order1) = 1
```

This is the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[ItemLink](
    [ItemKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemLinkRId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityId] [int] NULL,
    [Order1] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemLink] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemKey] ASC
)
)
```

This is the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[ItemLink1](
    [PriorityItemKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityDivisionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PriorityDesc] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ModifyUser] [dbo].[EditUser] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyStation] [dbo].[EditStation] NOT NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [dbo].[EditDate] NOT NULL,
    [CreateUser] [dbo].[EditUser] NOT NULL,
    [CreateStation] [dbo].[EditStation] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [dbo].[EditDate] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemLinkRPriority1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Priority1ItemKey] ASC
)
)
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: show your table design with sample data to illustrate your problem, use SQLFiddle if you can

Comment: Use term consistently.  Title is max but code is min.  order of 1 but code is order1

Comment: Ok, great, your question is much better now, but we still need the insert statements for the sample data as well as the desired result to fully understand what is your goal here.

Comment: If you GROUP BY ItemKey, and there's only one record per ItemKey, then your GROUP BY won't have any effect. What column do you use to determine if two items are of the same style? If it's ItemLinkRId, you should GROUP BY that column instead.